# Button Not Appearing in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

My `Button` is not appearing in tkinker (Python).
Here is the main Code:

```
# Start Of Manual Scanner ------------------------------------
manual = LabelFrame(tab_1,
                    text="Manual")
manual.pack(side=LEFT)
main = Label(manual,
             text="Manual Entry",
             font=('Arial', 20))
main.pack(side=TOP)
manual_entry = Entry(manual,
                     width=100,
                     font=('Arial', 20))
manual_entry.pack(side=RIGHT)
place_order_BTN = Button(manual,
                         text="Add Item",
                         fg='black',
                         font=('Arial', 20),
                         width=20,
                         bg='#feffa3',
                         activeforeground='white',
                         activebackground='black',)
place_order_BTN.pack(pady=15)
```

When I run it:

[image: screenshot of entire window]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem replacing `tab_1` with the root `Tk()` window. It looks like you may be using a `ttk.Notebook` which may have something to do with the problem. Please provide [mre], as there is not enough information in the snippet of code currently in your question.

Comment: The entry `manual_entry` is too long (100 characters width) and so the button is squished to zero width.  Try changing `manual_entry.pack(side=RIGHT)` to `manual_entry.pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

The button is actually packed to the left of the entry. However since the entry is a bit long (100 characters width), it squishes the button to zero width.

You can either make the entry a bit smaller:

```py
manual_entry = Entry(manual,
                     width=30,  # changed from 100 to 30
                     font=('Arial', 20))
manual_entry.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

[image]

or changing `manual_entry.pack(side=RIGHT)` to `manual_entry.pack()`.

[image]

Comment: What would happen if the `Button` was also explicitly given a `width`?

Comment: @martineau OP has already specified width option of the button.

Comment: Oops…you're right. I was just wondering why the `Button` didn't shrink the `Entry` instead of the other way around.